# Update State then Redirect with React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React 16.12.0, React Router DOM 5.1.2 for a project and have trouble with redirecting only after state has been successfully updated. Basically I have a button, that when on click, I'd like to update the state with the information that the user selected and then navigate to the home page and show a banner. I'm using React Hook useContext that wraps at one of the highest component level, and also the history object from React Router Dom.

The expected behavior:

- Context state property 'showBanner' is set to true
- Navigate to '/' page

The existing behavior:

- Navigate to '/' page
- Context state property 'showBanner' remains false

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
// Import statements - useHistory() from react-router-dom, useContext from react, etc.

const browse = (props) => {
  const {globalState, dispatchGlobalState} = useContext(myContext);
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    dispatchGlobalState( { type: 'showBanner', payload: true } );
    history.push('/');
  }

  return (
   <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
  )
```

I've also tried wrapping the dispatch in a Promise but no luck...

```
  const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    new Promise( (resolve, reject) ) => {
      dispatchGlobalState( { type: 'showBanner', payload: true } );
    })
    .then( () => {
      history.push('/');
    }));
```

I've also tried conditionally rendering a  element using local state, but no luck with that either. Does anyone have know what I might be doing wrong - how do I tell React to first do all my state updates, and only when that is finished, then redirect to another page?

Comment: I think there is a race condition happening out there. Although it's not a best practice but you can try setTimeout. i.e.  setTimeout(()=>history.push('/'),0)

Comment: Yeah it totally is a race condition. Since both operate asynchronously, there are times when the banner does show (meaning global state updated first, then redirect happens). And there are times when it doesn't show (meaning redirect fired first before global state got a chance to update).

Comment: Did setTimeOut worked?

Comment: I think we run into the same issue though. Even with the setTimeOut, there's still no guarantee that the dispatchGobalState will run successfully before it, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of useEffect to trigger a redirection. The dependency to useEffect will be your globalState which when changes the the redirection happens.

Make sure to not call the useEffect on initial render.

```
const browse = (props) => {
  const {globalState, dispatchGlobalState} = useContext(myContext);
  const history = useHistory();
  const isInitialRender = useRef(true);

  const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    dispatchGlobalState( { type: 'showBanner', payload: true } );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      if(!isInitialRender.current) {
         history.push('/');
      }else {
         isInitialRender.current = false;
      }

  }, [globalState])
  return (
   <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
  )
```